# python - Plotting bar graph side by side on the same graph with seaborn

Tags: python, seaborn, graphing

I need to try to plot 3 bars on the same graph. I have 2 dataframes set up right now. My first dataframe was created off a JSON file seen [here](https://pastebin.com/pBvuUKzW).

**My second dataframe was created in the code below:**

```
def make_bar_graph():
    with open('filelocation.json') as json_file:
        data = json.load(json_file)
        df = pd.DataFrame([])
        for item in data["Results"]["Result"]:
            df = df.append(pd.DataFrame.from_dict(kpi for kpi in item["KPI"]))
        df.reset_index(level=0, inplace= True)
        df.rename(columns={0: 'id', 1: 'average', 2:'std. dev', 3: 'min', 4: 
                  'median', 5:'max'}, inplace=True)
        wanted_x = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14]
        wanted_y = [5, 5, .500, .500, .500, 1, 1, 5, 5, .500, .500, .500, 1, 1]
        kpi = ['kpi1', 'kpi2', 'kpi3', 'kpi4', 'kpi5', 'kpi6', 'kpi7', 'kpi8', 'kpi9', 'kpi10', 'kpi11', 'kpi12',
           'kpi13', 'kpi14']
        df2 = pd.DataFrame(dict(x=wanted_x, y=wanted_y, kpi=kpi))
        sns.set()
        sns.set_context("talk")
        sns.axes_style("darkgrid")
        h = sns.barplot(x='id', y ='average', data=df.ix[0:13], label='Test 
                  on 4/30/2018', color='b')
        g = sns.barplot(x='id', y='average', data=df.ix[14:27], label='Test 
                  on 6/4/2018', color='r')
        k = sns.barplot("x", "y", data=df2, label='Desired Results', color='y')
        plt.legend()
        plt.xlabel('KPI number')
        plt.ylabel('Time(s)')
        plt.show()
```

**This is the graph I get from that:**

[Graph1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VactL.png)

I need the bars to be next to each other, separated by id (or KPI, id number and KPI number are the same things). I'm not sure how to rework my dataframe to do this